# how to clean reliably xml files before parsing?

Tags: xml, parsing

I'm parsing XML files coming from external sources with java (dom parser).
My files are "simple" they are always in the form:

```
<block1><tag1>...</tag1><tag2>...</tag2></block1>
<block2><tag1>...</tag1><tag2>...</tag2></block2>
...
```

However files break the parser for any sort of reasons:

- illegal chars &,>< in tag. I usually replace them with & etc or I protect them injecting a CDATA section
- characters \x00-\x1f which I must delete as they are not even protected by CDATA
- truncated tags:
- not closed blocks/tag: in this case also I would like to skip

How do I deal with this errors in a robust automatic manner?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, let's be clear: these are not XML files. You're not talking about processing XML, you're talking about processing non-XML.

If you want to do this reliably and robustly then you need to start with a specification of the (not-quite-XML) language that you want your program to accept, and you also need a specification of how you want this to be translated to XML. For example, your language might differ from XML by allowing an unescaped ampersand in certain contexts: you need to define what these contexts are (e.g any ampersand not followed by a letter or "#"; or you might allow an ampersand followed by a name provided the name is not followed by ";").

There are obviously multiple ways of doing this, for example you could interpret `<x>&lt</x>` either as `<x>&amp;lt</x>` or as `<x>&lt;</x>`. Only you can decide which is the intended meaning in the non-XML input that you are parsing.

Once you have a specification of what you want to do, writing a parser for this non-XML language is still challenging, but not half so challenging as doing it without a specification. But even with a clear and unambiguous specification, of course, there is no guarantee that every input file you ever encounter will conform to your particular quasi-XML dialect.

Comment: yes, you are right, I probably should accept they are not XML files even if they are supposedly generated by Standard WebServices Frameworks and Export tools. Unfortunately I don't have control on the generation of the files and considering that the hierarchy is "simple" (only one level), writing my own parser shouldn't be such a daunting task...

Comment: Don't give up hope on shaming the suppliers of these non-XML feeds into fixing their code.